# vimeo api video search call does not work for utf-8 characters

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

When I use turkish characters like `ş ç ğ` with vimeo playground it returns this response.

**Query**

```
İşletim
```

**request**

```
GET /api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.search&query=%C4%B0%C5%9Fletim HTTP/1.1
Host: vimeo.com
Accept: */*
```

**response**

```
{
  "generated_in": "0.0121",
  "stat": "ok",
  "videos":{
    "on_this_page": "0",
    "page": "1",
    "perpage": "50",
    "total": "0",
    "video":[

    ]
  }
}
```

However, I know there is a video has title **İşletim**